# How to check the availability of, and load, dynamic libraries in FORTRAN

Tags: linux, fortran, shared-libraries

I have written a FORTRAN library "B" which, depending on the way it is called, may or may not call routines in another library "C". The intent is for "B" to be used in applications "A".

So far, B and C are compiled as static libraries (.a files).
This means that C.a must be available and linked to when compiling B.a, which is okay.
This also means that C.a must be available when compiling the application A, even if A has no intention of using the functionality in B which depends on C. This is annoying and seems unnecessary, as one has to distribute C.a to users who will never use it.

Ideally I would want to have C as a dynamic/shared library, and in B do some run-time availability-check like this (pseudo-code):

```
if (requested feature from C)
    if (is_available(libC.so))
        call routine_from_C()
        (Go on...)
    else
        call Error("You need to install C")
else
    (We don't need C. Go on...)
```

Is something like this possible with FORTRAN on Linux?

Comment: Checking for a file should be possible with `INQUIRE` but loading it is, afaik, not possible. Thus I would try to write a C wrapper for the library and the loaded functions.

Comment: Is there perhaps some fancy Fortran2003-thing which can do this?

Comment: You can use the `ISO_C_BINDING` module to interoperate with C, but I guess, that's not, what you asked for. I'm not aware of any Fortran (2008) function, which would provide this functionality.

Comment: OK. Sometimes, search engines do their job: In the [Intel forums](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/268114), the corresponding functions `dlopen` and `dlsym` are called directly from Fortran. Using the `ISO_C_BINDING` module, you could convert his example to suit your needs.